# How do I manipulate strings using a for loop?

Tags: c#, string, for-loop

While attempting the problem 1768. Merge Strings Alternately on leetcode, I ran in to an issue with my for loop.

The goal is to merge two strings (word1 and word2) by alternating the letters of both strings (example: word1 = "abc", word2 = "def", the solution should then be "adbecf"). If the strings are of different lengths the end of the longer string should be appended to the merged string (example: word1 = "abc", word2 = "defgh", the solution to this should be "adbecfgh").

My code ran into no issues when it came to appending the end of longer strings. What it won't do is merge the beginning of the two strings alternately.

I tried using a for loop to append the letters one by one:

```
/*declare string*/
string merged = "";

/*add letters to string in alternating order*/
for (int i = 0; i <= word1.Length ^ i <= word2.Length; i ++)
{
    merged.Append(word1[i]);
    merged.Append(word2[i]);
}
```

I also tried adding the letters "arithmetically":

```
/*declare string*/
string merged = "";

/*add letters to string in alternating order*/
for (int i = 0; i <= word1.Length ^ i <= word2.Length; i ++)
{
    merged += word1[i];
    merged += word2[i];
}
```

Whenever I tried any of these methods merged returned as an empty string (merged = ""). Can anyone explain to me what I have done wrong?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using xor for the loop condition? It's far more readable to not hack it and just put the full condition in.

Comment: ^ isn't "hacking it" - it's just plain wrong !

Comment: @ListsOfArrays I am trying to make the for loop stop when either word1 or word2 has run out of letters. Would you say there is a more effective way to declare the loop condition?

Comment: Consider using a `StringBuilder`. Doing string concatenation in a loop is never a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *actual* problem has nothing to do with string manipulation and is caused by your `for` condition: `^` is the exclusive or operator, so the condition is initially false, because both `<=` checks will always evaluate true at first (since 0 is less than or equal the length of *any* string), and `true ^ true` is false. The result is execution never enters the loop, hence why `merged` is still an empty string at the end. As a tip, you would have realised this very quickly if you had stepped in your code line by line with a debugger.

You should use `&&` instead. Also, you want to compare with `<`, not `<=`, because strings in C# are just like arrays, they end one index before their length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word1.Length && i < word2.Length; i++)
```

Now that this is fixed, let's talk string manipulation.

In your first case, you're actually using the LINQ method `Append`, which is available because a string is a sequence of chars. This doesn't actually append anything, but rather returns an enumerable sequence that, when enumerated, will give the items of both one after the other.

In your second case, you're using `string`'s operator `+=`, which, since C# strings are immutable, creates a new copy every time. It works, but it's inefficient. So, instead, you should use `StringBuilder`, which is a mutable string. You can do various operations on it, and when you're done editing your string, use `ToString()` to get a final immutable copy as a string:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < word1.Length && i < word2.Length; i++)
{
    builder.Append(word1[i]);
    builder.Append(word2[i]);
}

var merged = builder.ToString();
```

It's much faster.

Comment: ^ is a bitwise operator, so would it convert Length to true or actually work on the bits in the size_t (or whatever C# uses for length) ?

Comment: @John3136 For booleans, it's still a logical operation (the difference is that it doesn't short-circuit): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-

Comment: Understood, but length isn't a Boolean. Ahh, but i <= Length is. Silly question - I should have read it more carefully :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to assume that anyone using `^` will be using it with integers, but maybe they are simply misguided ;)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It never occurred to me that C# strings might have been immutable!